# Activate MouseEvent on Edit Button click C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Form with textboxes and they have MouseEvent(MouseMove, MouseDown) and they are enabled on form load, but my question is how to call them just when i Click the Edit Button, so just then the textboxes can move?

My code:

```
 private void textBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = sender as TextBox;
        foreach (TextBox text in textBoxs)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (txt.Name == text.Name)
                {
                    txt.Left = e.X + txt.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
                    txt.Top = e.Y + txt.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void textBox_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

   private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnEdit.Visible = false;
        btnPrint.Visible = false;
        btnSave.Visible = true;

        //Want to call mouse function here.

    }
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hooking the events from the Visual Studio designer, you should manually hook the events in the `btnEdit_Click` handler method by adding this line:

```
textboxname.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(textBox_MouseMove);
```

Then unhook the event when your save button is clicked (I'm assuming you have some method `btnSave_Click`) by doing the following:

```
textboxname.MouseMove -= new MouseEventHandler(textBox_MouseMove);
```

The same goes for your `MouseDown` event.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your post, you want the textbox functionality to become "active" after you click the `btnEdit` button?

You could set a flag in `btnEdit_Click`, and only process the functionality in the other functions if that flag is true

Or, maybe add the event in the `btnEdit_Click` function, e.g.

```
private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnEdit.Visible = false;
    btnPrint.Visible = false;
    btnSave.Visible = true;

    //Want to call mouse function here.

    textBox.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(textBox_MouseDown);

}
```

But remove that extra line from where it currently exists in your code.